# Why is my publish vb project run smoothly in one computer but not the others?

Tags: vb.net

I have published my vb project using install wizard and i even tried with *inno setup* both of the *setup.exe* :

- can install and run on comp1 (Windows 7 32-bit with Visual Studio 2010)
- can install but cannot run on comp2 (Windows 7 64-bit)
- cannot install and run on comp3 (Windows 7 64-bit)

what can i do about it? I need the *setup.exe* to run on all comp1,2,3.

Comment: what is the error prompted ? and is the logged in user have software installation rights?

Comment: Error Signature : event type : clr20r3

Comment: Are you installing **all** the required reference libraries? What does your setup in install wizard look like? Need more detailes, *clr20r3* does not constrain the source of your predicament sufficiantly.

Comment: i got it already. i redo everything and made adjustment to the platform setting and the preaquisition from default .NET Framework 4 Client to .NET Framework.. thanks for your advise..